# Animate removing views from complex scrollview

Tags: android, android-animation, android-scrollview

I am trying to remove some Views from a ScrollView, but do so with a nice animation effect.

Unfortunately, android:animateLayoutChanges does not appear to work inside ScrollView with multiple ViewGroups. More precisely, in that case you can only apply it to a subset view. In such a situation, however, the other views will still adjust by jumping into position.

I have used TranslateAnimation to slide everything inside a ScrollView into place, removing the views onAnimationEnd. This appears only to work if a ScrollView does not scroll (content smaller than ScrollView size).

Simplified code:

```
Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, -ViewToBeRemoved.getHeight());

animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
...
   @Override
   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
      viewToBeRemoved.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}

scrollViewChildView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Is there a way to remove Views from a ScrollView with an animation?

Comment: Yes animation is no problem if you do it right, but first I would like to reiterate that `animateLayoutChanges` does in fact work! The trick is to put it on the root node of the content inside the `ScrollView`. It would be best if there were a `LinearLayout` as root for the content in the `ScrollView`. Then it should animate any changes like [**it is demonstrated here**](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html).

Comment: It does not work as soon as you add ViewGroups under the top level child.